# Google-Line-Chart on hover tool-tip not showing value

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization, linechart

I have used [Google Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) in Angular2 in typescript version, When I draw the line chart, Chart is looking good but when I hover over the line chart to see what is exact value at that point, I can't see any value in tool-tip and I don't understand what can be the problem if the value has been drawn in chart but aren't showing up in tool-tip.I have attached a screenshot for the reference. Sample data array which gets convert into datatable is as follow:

```
Gdata = [
["TimeStamp", "Temparature"], [Sat May 13 2017 10:45:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 23.81], [Sat May 13 2017 10:50:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 23.83], [Sat May 13 2017 10:55:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 23.90], [Sat May 13 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 23.85], [Sat May 13 2017 11:05:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 23.82]
];
```

[image: Google Line Chart Blank Data Issue]

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After spending a lot time in this issue, I finally found that value was present in that tool-tip but as you can see the tool-tip is getting cut at the boundary of chart. Can anyone help me with correcting this tool-tip to look with some width within that boundary and should take only that much length which is required by it to show the content. Similar to https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#standard-tooltips

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the many options provided by google charts, I found an option called `tooltip: { isHtml: true }` which worked for me and now tooltip is showing within the chart area only.